how can I hover a div tag and add border to that without changing the original size of it
when I hover over my div (and border when hover), size of that button change, so other element position change too.
JSX
<div className="container">
        <div className="contact">Contact us</div>
        <div className="about">About us</div>
</div>

CSS
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 25px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.contact {
  padding: 25px 45px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(264deg, #df8908 -5.09%, #b415ff 106.2%);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.about {
  padding: 25px 75px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.contact:hover {
  border: 4px solid white;
}
.about:hover {
  border-color: #b415ff;
}

box-sizing is border-box
I expect no change in size of first div.

Do you have tried giving .contact a border in advance as .about?

Yes. I have had done it. it does not work

I cannot explain to you, why it does not work with flex. But I meant https://jsfiddle.net/TRNCFRMCN/bey60csj/10/

I had made a mistake, I fixed it after seeing your code. thank you
